# How to interpret image_size parameter in AI Platform built-in classification algorithm?

Tags: tensorflow, image-classification, google-ai-platform

I'm following the "[Getting started with the built-in image classification algorithm](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/algorithms/image-classification-start#gcloud)" tutorial from Google's AI Platform and before submit a training job, one has to specify (it seems optional) the "image_size" which is defined as: "the image size (width and height) used for training". Do I have to specify a couple of scalars (comma delimited?) or a scalar ? How can we interpret this parameter? If I specify something, does it impose that all my input images should be of this particular size or will the images be automatically resized (or cropped?) to this size by the training graph? And equivalently for prediction task do I have to resize my input image to this specific size or does the prediction graph takes care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have not used the built in classifier however I am pretty sure you should specify the images as as a tuple of integers like (200,300). The classifier will read in your images and convert all of them to this size automatically.